# How To Pass Navigation in CustomDrawerContent

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Hello It's my First time using React native
i want to pass navigation in CustomDrawerContent so i can go to another page when i click MILES SELIM text

```js
function CustomDrawerContent({progress, ...rest }) {
// Animated Code here
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...rest}>
      <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateX }] }}>
        <View {...rest}>
        <Text onPress={() => rest.navigation.navigate('MainScreen')} style={styles.name}>MILES SELIM</Text>
        </View>
        {Drawer item code here}
      </Animated.View>
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="MainScreen" drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />} drawerStyle={{
            backgroundColor: '#0094FF',
        }}
        drawerContentOptions={{
            activeBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
            labelStyle:{
                fontSize:16,
                color:"#fff"
            }
          }}>
        {... Screen here}
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

The error says: "The action Navigate with payload {name:"MainScreen"} was not handled by any navigator
Heres what i've done so far

Comment: You are accessing navigation correctly, if you have a screen called MainScreen then it should work

Comment: When you are inside a navigator you always have navigation prop available, are you getting navigation prop in the drawer content or not? but as you a custom component you can pass manually from the navigator to your component.

Comment: Thanks i figured it out im just calling a wrong name here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After figuring it out im just calling a wrong name here it's because im calling a component instead of name

```
onPress={() => rest.navigation.navigate('MainScreen')}
<Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen}>
```

it should be

```
onPress={() => rest.navigation.navigate('Main')}
<Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you check by console.log in if you are getting the navigation on your custom drawer component? If you are getting the navigation then there shouldn't be any issue with navigation.navigate.

```
console.log(...rest);
```

Do this before the return function.

For more info check this [React Navigation Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/)

Comment: Thanks i figured it out im just calling a wrong name here..

Comment: Yeah im running out of ideas with this one doing 3 hours figuring it out and doing 5 different approach with this one and finally post the problem here damn haha